# Rails Display results in view format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, slim-lang

I need to show a result in view
but format is not pretty
my code

```
      - @patient.weight.each do |m|
    tr
      td  = m.date
      td  = m.weight
      td  = m.weight  / (@patient.weight.first.inch * @patient.weight.first.inch).to_f
```

this result in webpage

```
02/09/2014  23.44   6.4930747922437675
```

i need to show only in column 3,  6.49
need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `round` with a parameter containing the number of decimal you want.

```
>> 6.4930747922437675.round(2)
=> 6.49
```

So, just change your line to

```
td  = (m.weight  / (@patient.weight.first.inch * @patient.weight.first.inch).to_f).round(2)
```

This solve my problem to avoid erros in view

```
- @patient.weight.each do |m|
    tr
      - if m.date != nil
          td = m.date
      - else
          td = 'Sem pesos registrados'

      - if m.weight != nil
          td  = m.weight
      - else
          td  = 'sem peso registrado'

      - if @patient.weight.first.inch != nil
          td  = (m.weight / (@patient.weight.first.inch**2).to_f).round(2)
      - else
          td  = 'sem dados para este calculo'
```

br

Comment: I'm not sure to understand correctly what you mean. If I'm correct, you can do ````td = (@patient.weight > 0 ? (m.weight  / (@patient.weight.first.inch * @patient.weight.first.inch).to_f).round(2) : "no weight for patient")````

Answer (score 0):

Short form would be

```
td = (m.weight / (@patient.weight.first.inch**2).to_f).round(2)
```

If you always want to have a precision of 2, you could also use the `number_with_precision` helper  ([Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_precision))

```
td = number_with_precision(m.weight / (@patient.weight.first.inch**2).to_f, precision: 2)
```

Comment: How can i put an code if patient dont have weight show no weight for patient?